# How can I know if my Word app is minimized and when its not minimized using a word add-in?

Tags: javascript, ms-word, office-js, office-addins, word-addins

I am trying to build an add-in for Microsoft Word which sends a ping to an API using `setInterval` every few seconds when the Word app is not minimized.

The problem is that it still sends a ping even when the Word app *is* minimized, how can I prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

If your Add-In runs in the browser version of Office (Word, Excel, etc) you can use "Document.visibilityState".

Unfortunately, it does not work for the Installed PC version.
Does anybody know how check this for the installed versions?

Comment: yes, I already knew this solution for the browser but my problem is also for the PC version.